# iam service account documentation discrepancy

Tags: service-accounts, google-deployment-manager

There is a discrepancy between the documentation for an [IAM V1 Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts) and the example shown in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/project_creation/service-accounts.py.

The document shows that the properties has a 'name' field, with a value that looks like projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{UNIQUE_ID}. The other properties that can be set are 'displayName' and 'description'.

The example does not have the name and description properties, but instead has 'accountId' and 'projectId'.

I am confused as to which is the correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

Ecample on Github is old : `Latest commit 81378b1 on Mar 4, 2017` and the documentation was updated more recently: `Last updated 2020-08-18 UTC` which means that some of the field names have changed and example is not correct.

To correct this you may file an issue on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

**Always use whatever is in the official documentation** - it's the best source of reference if in doubt.